# Cannot convert type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' to generic.list<T>

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a class `R` with some properties.

Similarly I have a `DataTable` `dt` with columns exactly same as the properties of the class `R`

I am trying to create 2 different `DataTables` from the above said `DataTable` `dt` based on a condition on one of the columns of the `dt`.

And I want to convert these 2 `Datatables` into a `List` of `R` objects.

This is how I am trying with now progress:

```
List<R> Sheet1 = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row["SomeDecimalColumn"]) <= Convert.ToDecimal(80));

List<R> Sheet2 = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row["SomeDecimalColumn"]) > Convert.ToDecimal(80));
```

But it throws an error:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection' to generic.list

I tried doing all kinds of casting but with no use:

```
List<R> Sheet1 = (List<R>)dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row["SomeDecimalColumn"]) <= Convert.ToDecimal(80));

List<R> Sheet2 = (List<R>)dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row["SomeDecimalColumn"]) > Convert.ToDecimal(80));
```

---

```
List<R> Sheet1 = (List<R>)dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row["SomeDecimalColumn"]) <= Convert.ToDecimal(80))
    .ToList();

List<R> Sheet2 = (List<R>)dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row["SomeDecimalColumn"]) > Convert.ToDecimal(80))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What is `R` here? Try using `st.Select` method or use `var` instead of List<R>

Comment: What is `R`? If it's not a subclass of `System.Data.Row`, you'll need to write code to initialize a new `R` from an existing `System.Data.Row`. Casting isn't magic. When you cast A to B, A must *be* a B, or there must be some code invoked that converts an A *into* a B.

Comment: You really have classes like `R`? Shorter names werent available? I guess your first class was `A`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have used R for representational purpose, since i did not want to violate my company's policy.

Comment: @S.Akbari thanks,that worked. I do have another issue, how can we sort a dataview's numeric column? i am using dv.Sort()="mynumericcolumnname desc" but  it only sorts as strings(i.e. 9 comes first instead of 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Where` statement is returning [`EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907979(v=vs.110).aspx). You need to select a `List` of `R` from your query to make this works:

```
List<R> Sheet1 = dt.AsEnumerable().
      Where(row => Convert.ToDecimal(row["SomeDecimalColumn"]) <= Convert.ToDecimal(80))
     .Select(c => new R 
      { SomeDecimalColumn = Convert.ToDecimal(c["SomeDecimalColumn"]) /*other propertie*/ })
     .ToList();
```